# What do do with someone clearly showing they don't want to learn the language/environment their question is for?

Tags: discussion, abuse

See these two questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280495/dataaccess-in-delphi-7

[From .NET to Delphi, an ERP on Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272978/from-net-to-delphi-an-erp-on-delphi)

Some suspect these two questions are from the same user.

Both questions clearly show the asker has no interest in learning.

What to do?

- about the question
- about the bashing in the answers and comments

The second question got a lot of downvotes, the first a few.
Is that the way to go?

I'm considering posting an answer like this one that I posted on LinkedIn not too long ago (which a lot of people liked).
Is that appropriate?

> I've been hearing 'Delphi is dead' since Delphi 1 (which tomorrow was released 15 years ago).
>
> Delphi has it's place, .NET as it's place and other development tools/environments have their place too.
>      The true developer knows when too choose what, and how to be more productive than the people doing only one thing.
>
> All this bashing stuff is soooo stone-age. Modern languages (including Delphi, Java, C#, VB.NET) are all great languages. I have done projects and trained people in all 4 mentioned languages, all with really nice results.
>      For some people it is easier to learn a few than others (background plays a role here, what languages do you know, and is it easy for you to learn something totally different).
>
> I totally agree with Ralph that languages and environments don't die.
>      COBOL is still very much used, as are Clipper and many others.

--jeroen

Comment: Flag them for mod attention as "troll"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What do do with someone clearly showing they don’t want to learn the language/environment their question is for?

Choose one or more:

- Answer their question
- Don't answer their question
- Vote to close the question if it doesn't meet site guidelines
- Downvote or upvote the question according to the site guidelines and your own impression

You will meet many, many, many people in the world that are not interested in improving their skills, and scrape along in life by knowing just enough, but no more.  They aren't interested in analysis and synthesis, just applying their knowledge.

While that person may not benefit from your answer, others may come along later with a thirst for knowledge and happen upon your answer.

In other words, it doesn't matter whether they will learn and grow.  Do what you would normally do.

Comment: Agreed. I don't come to these sites to judge someone based off of their personal goals, just to answer and ask questions. If someone does something you think goes against what the site is for just downvote it.

Comment: @Dynamo:  I like helping people by answering their questions.  If there's no evidence that the questioner will benefit from an answer, there goes my motivation.  Therefore, I'm on the don't answer/do downvote side.  I can't honestly vote to close, since they're real, if incredibly stupid, questions about programming.

Comment: I like the community thing here (coming from a Delphi background which has had a very strong community since the beginning, it is good to see something similar gaining lots of momentum), so I'd rather not downvote but answer as others benefit from them. Downvoting makes it harder for others (that do benefit) to find those answers. It's a delicate balance, hence my question :-) So I've followed Neil's advise: flag for moderation.